# Is there a way to record what is displayed in Android's Camera Preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

There are already plenty of threads about the android's front camera mirror flip issue but non of them answered my concern.

I just wanted to know if its possible to record what the Camera Preview is currently displaying instead of the media recorder's?

This way, I can be sure that the mirror image is what is going to be written to disk.

Comment: Send the output of the preview to a MediaRecorder's input Surface (API 21+). Older API levels require different answers.

Comment: gee thanks for the comment, exactly what i needed. i guess i should read the docs more thoroughly :D